# Is there a way to make an object move between two points linearly?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm making a 2D Shooter, I have a target object set up and I'm trying to make it move from point A to point B at a constant speed.

I tried using a timeline set to go between a value of 1 and -1 over 4 seconds to drive the alpha of a Lerp node but this causes an ease-in-out effect.

[image]

I want to be able to set two vectors for the object to move between at a constant speed. Right now I don't know of any other node that can flip between a value over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Make these two thingies please, add an actor and all that fun stuff, and you will place two checkpoints in the level.]

[image: BluePrintOverview in the moving actor]

Alrighty, first, avoid event tick like the plague, it adds quite a bit of processing overhead to the game, but 
for this we are going to make two Checkpoint objects and use that to do a **get all actors from class**, you can set up other logics for this using loops but right now we are going to keep it simple. And in the moving object we are going to do a "**Get All Actors of Class**" and since it is only two actors we are going to use a **ForEachLoop** to set each of them to a variable (just promote to variable off of the blue thingie on your loop) 
We are using a sequence and branch, this way it will check with each tick of the foreach loop to make sure that checkpoint one (array index 0) is set to the right index in the array, and that checkpoint two (array index 1) is set to the right index of the array, once it is completed it will fire off the completed and start the object move events.

[image: Here is your setcheckpoint logic, we are going to store the checkpoint object itself as a variable and use that to **get location** off of]

[image: The move to macro logic]

Now from here we are going to have the object do a move to to a check point, and once it is there it will fire the completed and it will trigger the **custom event** to move to the next checkpoint. Make sure when you do this that you also add one of those event calls to your event begin play line.

Comment: Thanks, this works way better than the way I had it set up, it works as expected but I can only have one target and one set of movement points. How can I set the movement points per target?

Comment: Expand a little, do you want to have more targets that are moving on different paths? Well with this you can spawn in several moving objects if you want them to all go on the same path, is that what you had in mind? I do have a setup that I use for setting up checkpoints for several different paths if you would find that useful.

Comment: I think I made a system I'm working with pretty well, I made two scene components on the targets I get their World position (Vec A) and add another vector (Vec B) to that, I can edit Vec B in the Details panel.

Comment: @ShadyHorizon If you want to have multiple predefined paths with checkpoints I highly suggest you combine that timeline with a Spline component, which you can build on runtime or preset on the level. It all depends on what you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

Open timeline and set the curve to linear , select all points of the curve, right click and then choose linear, this will fix your issue.
And then use reverse output to play it backward to move back and force.